# How to create an array from all combinations of the vector components?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

Say I have vectors `{a,b,c}` and `{w,x,y,z}`. How can I get Mathematica to output an array `{{a,w},{a,x},{a,y},{a,z},{b,w},{b,x},{b,y},{b,z},{c,w},{c,x},{c,y},{c,z}}` where we have all combinations of the vector components matched up. I can do this with some for loops but I'm hoping that I'm missing an easier way of doing this.

Probably, the equivalent of the `expand.grid` function in **R**. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z}}]`

Comment: @cvgmt sorry, just saw your comment. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: @lericr For the convenience of the reader,keep the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z}}]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, {a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z} ], 1]
(*{{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z},{c,w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Also:

```
Distribute[{{a, b, c},{w, x, y, z}}, List]
```

> {{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c,
> w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}

Answer (score 6):

```
la = {a, b, c};

lb = {w, x, y, z};

Join @@ Outer[List, la, lb]
```

{{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c,
w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}

Answer (score 6):

```
Sequence @@ Thread[{#, {w, x, y, z}}] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c,
> w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `Through` and `Thread`:

```
f = Splice@Thread[{#[[0]], #[[1]]}] & /@ Through[#1[#2]] &;

f[{a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z}]
```

*Result*:

> {{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c,
> w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}

Or using `TensorProduct`:

```
Sequence @@@ Map[List @@ # &, TensorProduct[{a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z}], {2}]
```

*Result*:

> {{a, w}, {a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, w}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c,
> w}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}